# Executing Oracle stored procedure with XMLTYPE Output and capturing it in a SSIS variable

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, ssis, xmltype

I am in desperate need of help with executing an Oracle stored procedure that takes an XML of Oracle XMLTYPE as input and Outputs an XML of Oracle XMLTYPE.

I should be able to execute this Oracle stored procedure using SSIS Execute SQL Task with an Input variable mapping and an OUTPUT variable mapping.

I tried with OLEDB adapter and ADO.NET adapter but not successful in getting it to work.

I was able to make the Input variable type work by using expressions to build the script but not able to get the Output.

If anyone has worked on executing Oracle stored procedures with XMLTYPE data types, it would be of great help if you could point me in the right direction

Here is the Oracle stored procedure I was trying to execute in SSIS.

```
declare
  x_api_call XMLTYPE := XMLTYPE('<APICall><SeqID>110682</SeqID></APICall>');
  x_result XMLTYPE; 
BEGIN
  XML_READ_API.GET_PERSON ( p_api_call => x_api_call, p_result => x_result );
END;
```

I was trying to execute the above Oracle procedure in SSIS as below and having tough time determining the variable connection type and the variable type that I should use to capture the XML.

```
declare
BEGIN
  XML_READ_API.GET_PERSON ( p_api_call => ?, p_result => ? );
END;
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Paul, I'm trying to do the same thing. Have you found a solution/workaround for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

`Xmltype` is a complex thing and contains binary representation of XML document. So there are very low possibility of it's standardization as interface type between two such different systems.

Try to pass XML as text in `CLOB` parameter:

```
declare
  x_result XMLTYPE; 
BEGIN
  XML_READ_API.GET_PERSON ( p_api_call => XMLTYPE(?), p_result => x_result );
  ? := x_result.getCLOBVal;
END;
```

[**<kbd>SQLFiddle illustration</kbd>**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c8035/2)